# Not able to use hibernate classes in Apache Spark

Tags: hibernate, apache-spark

I am trying to use Apache Spark to do high speed computation. The results of this computation needs to be stored in Oracle.

I am using hibernate to do this. But since certain classes in hibernate like (JDBCTransaction) are not serializable - when they are used they throw a java.io.NotSerializableException: org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction), spark cluster does not support using hibernate.

Is there any work around to use hibernate to work with spark ?

I tried using byte code injection to mark JDBCTransaction class as serializable, but it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: unread block data exception.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to create a Transaction object in your driver, and execute transactions on RDD partitions. This is why you're getting serializable exceptions; the spark execution is trying to send the transaction object to a remote process, which obviously won't work. Even if you could serialize it, it would not be valid to use the same transaction object in multiple remote parallel transactions.

If you need to write data to the database in parallel, you should probably look at [RDD.foreachPartition()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD), which would allow you to create a database connection and transaction locally for each separate paritition/process.

If the data you want to write to the database is relatively small, you might instead collect() it, which returns it as objects local to the driver, then you can write to the database from there.