# Can I mark POJO as Hibernate entity, while this POJO is used by Apache Spark?

Tags: java, hibernate, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The project I currently worked with has some POJO files that being used by Spark in a way below:

```
    JavaRDD<MyPojo> = ...
    sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, MyPojo.class);
```

However, I also need to load the MySQL table into this POJO using normal Java code. I can use native SQL to load and wrap the data using the POJO. But I am also wondering if I am allowed to mark this POJO as Hibernate Entity.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see why not, what have you tried so far? Curious about your end goal too, as Spark can save to the MySQL instance as well.

Comment: @jgp, Thanks for your reply. The goal is when it is heavy computation, our system will try to use spark to save the the mysql db. However, when it is light weight task, we are trying to do it through rest api. The reason I doubt if I can use the same pojo for both these two ways is because I see some one post at here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29074114/not-able-to-use-hibernate-classes-in-apache-spark
But I am not sure if he is trying to do the same thing.

Comment: It sounds similar. I'll try to answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you use RDD or dataset/dataframe of a POJO, Hibernate/JPA annotations should not interfere.

However, be careful about where your code is running when you "play" with Spark.

If you want your executor to talk to the database via Hibernate, then they will have to open an Hibernate session. I do not know (or think) that the Hibernate session can be serializable and shared between your driver and the executor.

If you have have your Hibernate session in your driver and want to save the data at this point, remember that you will have to transfer all the data from the executors to the driver (through a `collect()`-like method for example).

It might change a bit the architecture of your application, but I would consider a call to `write()`:

```
df.write()
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .jdbc(dbConnectionUrl, "ch02", prop);
```

Not that this is done with a dataframe, which is a `Dataset<Row>`, not a `Dataset<MyPojo>` (and not a RDD). The full example is:

```
package net.jgp.books.spark.ch02.lab100_csv_to_db;

import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.concat;
import static org.apache.spark.sql.functions.lit;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SaveMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

/**
 * CSV to a relational database.
 * 
 * @author jgp
 */
public class CsvToRelationalDatabaseApp {

  /**
   * main() is your entry point to the application.
   * 
   * @param args
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    CsvToRelationalDatabaseApp app = new CsvToRelationalDatabaseApp();
    app.start();
  }

  /**
   * The processing code.
   */
  private void start() {
    // Creates a session on a local master
    SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder()
        .appName("CSV to DB")
        .master("local")
        .getOrCreate();

    // Step 1: Ingestion
    // ---------

    // Reads a CSV file with header, called authors.csv, stores it in a
    // dataframe
    Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
        .format("csv")
        .option("header", "true")
        .load("data/authors.csv");

    // Step 2: Transform
    // ---------

    // Creates a new column called "name" as the concatenation of lname, a
    // virtual column containing ", " and the fname column
    df = df.withColumn(
        "name",
        concat(df.col("lname"), lit(", "), df.col("fname")));

    // Step 3: Save
    // ----

    // The connection URL, assuming your PostgreSQL instance runs locally on the
    // default port, and the database we use is "spark_labs"
    String dbConnectionUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/spark_labs";

    // Properties to connect to the database, the JDBC driver is part of our
    // pom.xml
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.setProperty("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver");
    prop.setProperty("user", "jgp");
    prop.setProperty("password", "Spark<3Java");

    // Write in a table called ch02
    df.write()
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .jdbc(dbConnectionUrl, "ch02", prop);

    System.out.println("Process complete");
  }
}
```